# HTML accessible tables - does th have to be the first column in a row?

Tags: html, html-table, accessibility

This is a government financial table so I can't reorder the columns. The first column is an account code, the second column is the name of the account. If I do:

```
<thead><tr><th scope="col">Account Code</th><th scope="col">Account Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>12345</td><th scope="row">Fish and Wildlife</th></tr>
...
</tbody>
```

Will validation barf on that and will screen readers parse it correctly?

Comment: Why would it? Have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the specifications they do not specify a need for the th to appear as the first column in a table row, and so you should be able to put the th wherever you want.

```
Table cells may either contain "header" information (see the TH element) or "data" (see the TD element).
```

[HTML w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/tables.html)

Answer (score 2):

`<th>` just denotes a "header cell", they can exist in `<thead>`, `<tbody>` and `<tfoot>` as appropriate for the content.

You've got your column headers in `<thead>` and within `<th>` cells, so the markup you've provided is both schema-correct and in-line with accessibility guidelines. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

It's fine. The [example in the HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-th-element.html#dom-th-scope) is just like that.

Note however, that the `<th scope="row">` cell is only a header for those `td` cells to the right of it, and not for the `td` cell to the left of it (i.e. the account code).

You could add a `headers` attribute to each account code `td` to point to the account name `th` on the same row, but you'll need to assign a unique id for the account name `th` on each row.

Comment: Yeah, but the tables are hundreds of lines long, so adding all those IDs is going to make the code pretty ugly.  Still it may be what I have to do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ran this document through the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) and it came up clean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>I AM YOUR DOCUMENT TITLE REPLACE ME</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table>
<thead><tr><th scope="col">Account Code</th><th scope="col">Account Name</th></tr></thead>
<tbody><tr><td>12345</td><th scope="row">Fish and Wildlife</th></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

other than char encoding, which can't be checked because I'm pasting into their document.

Comment: The validator is only concerned with the correctness of the markup when compared with the HTML schema. It does not check accessibility issues.

Comment: Correct, but he was asking about whether "validation will barf on that" as well.